# XNA Project Dependencies not working/loading - monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Started a monogame project yesterday, was working perfectly fine, loaded up the project this morning and Visual Studio has decided that Xna doesn't exist:

```
the type or namespace name 'xna' does not exist in the namespace 'microsoft'
```

This is the error I'm getting in the Error List, alone with related things like GraphicsDeviceManager, Game, SpriteBatch etc.

I'm confused as I closed the project multiple times yesterday, so it surely isn't something to do with closing and deleting some dependency (but of course I could be completely wrong).

This is my first time using Xna in anyway, so I'm not too familiar with it either.

Comment: https://community.monogame.net/t/cs0234-the-type-or-namespace-name-xna-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft-are-you-missing-an-assembly-reference/16045

Comment: For some reason, uninstalling and reinstalling the content builder seems to fix this, wonder why?

Comment: Maybe it was lacking a reference towards xna? Good to hear you got it fixed though

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio has issues with loading `SDK` style projects in a timely manor.

All NuGet packages must be updated and loaded prior to the initialization of IntelliSense, if IntelliSense initialization times out, it ignores all loaded packages.

On the plus side, builds should still work. So IntelliSense errors may be ignored.